# Can't create a leader board for games in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect, game-center

I'm new for creating the leaderboard. I have problem on it. I don't have any board name with the name that I created. But it is showing "The Leaderboard Reference Name you entered has already been used. Enter a unique reference name and try again.["LeaderBoard name"]". I am trying this for past two days still the problem is there. Can anyone tell me what is the problem and what needs to do?

Step 1: I create a single leaderboard.

[image]

Step 2: Adding Language for that created leaderboard.

[image]

Step 3: I saved the created leaderboard but it doesn't create it and gives error message.

[image]

I tried with different leaderboard reference name but getting same error message. Please guide me to create this.

Answer (score 0):

The name must be unique in all of the apps.  Suggested is to do a reversed domain style "com.yourname.yourappname" or something similar...

In short - it has to be unique not just to you - but to everyone.

Comment: @R Bradshaw: Thanks for your response. We have tried many different names but same warning  message is showing. I have think its an iTunes connect error. Some how i have created the ids for my game.